# Countdown Timer is pausing everytime enter is pressed. How do I stop this bug from happening?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a word game component in React where there is a countdown timer that starts at 60 seconds and counts down. The user has to read the word that is displayed on the screen and then type it in. Once they have typed it and press enter, it should check the answer, add a score to the correct or incorrect place, clear the input field, and then the game continues. However, I have found that there is a bug, where everytime you press enter, the timer pauses briefly while it is obviously doing something in the background. I can't work out what is causing this behaviour to fix it. I assume something is re-rendering in the background, but am not sure what it is.

Here is the component code...

```
function TheBigScreen() {

  const inputElement = useRef(null);

  // Initial state for correct and incorrect answers
  const [correctAnswers, setCorrectAnswers] = useState(0);
  const [incorrectAnswers, setIncorrectAnswers] = useState(0);

  // Initial state for the selected word
  const wordsArray = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "date", "elderberry"];
  const [selectedWord, setSelectedWord] = useState("");

  // Initial state for user input
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

  // State to control the word display and fade animation
  const [showWord, setShowWord] = useState(true);

  // ****************************** FUNCTIONS ****************************** //

  function chooseNewWord() {
    // Update the selected word from the array
    setSelectedWord(wordsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsArray.length)]);
    setShowWord(true);
  }

  // Handle user input changes
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setUserInput(e.target.value);
  };

  // Handle Input Changes from Keyboard Component
  const handleInputUpdateFromKeyboard = (character) => {
    const inputField = document.getElementById("input-field");
    if (inputField) {
      inputField.value += character;
      inputField.focus();
    }
  };

  // Check the user's input and update answer counts
  const checkAnswer = () => {
    if (userInput === selectedWord) {
      setCorrectAnswers(correctAnswers + 1);
      // Get a new random word
      setSelectedWord(() => {
        chooseNewWord();
      });
    } else {
      setIncorrectAnswers(incorrectAnswers + 1);
      handleWordClick();
    }

    // Clear the user input
    setUserInput("");
  };

  // Handle "Enter" key press in the input field
  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      checkAnswer();
    }
  };

  // Function to handle clicking the blurred word
  const handleWordClick = () => {
    setShowWord(true); // Reveal the word

    if (inputElement.current) {
      inputElement.current.focus(); // Refocus on Input
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowWord(false); // After 2 seconds, hide it again
    }, 2000);
  };

  const onTimerEnd = () => {
    console.log("Timer has ended.");
  };

  // *************************** USE EFFECTS *************************** //

  useEffect(() => {
    chooseNewWord();
  }, []);

  // Effect to manage the initial word display and blur animation
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (selectedWord && showWord) {
      // Initially, show the word for 3 seconds
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setShowWord(false);
      }, 3000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [selectedWord, showWord]);

  return (
    <div className="TheBigScreen-Container">
      <div className="GameHeader">
        <div className="Header-Back-Button">
          <BackButton
            title="Exit"
            onclick={handleExit}
            className="Back-Button"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="Header-Title">
          <h3 className="GameName">The Big Screen</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="TheBigScreen-Content">
        <div className="TopLeft-Content">
          <Timer onTimerEnd={onTimerEnd} />
        </div>

        <div className="TopMiddle-Content">
          <div className="word-display">
            {showWord ? (
              <div className="word">{selectedWord}</div>
            ) : (
              <div className="word-blur" onClick={handleWordClick}>
                Word Hidden
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="word-actions">
            <span className="icon" onClick={playSound}>
              <FaVolumeUp alt="Play Sound" className="PlaySoundIcon" />
            </span>
            <span className="icon" onClick={displayMeaning}>
              <FaBook alt="Display Meaning" className="DisplayMeaningIcon" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="TopRight-Content">
          <div className="answer-count">
            <FaCheckSquare alt="Tick" className="Tick" />
            <p>:</p>
            <p>{correctAnswers}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="answer-count">
            <FaCut alt="Cross" className="Cross" />
            <p>:</p>
            <p>{incorrectAnswers}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="Input-Content">
        <div className="Middle-Content">
          <div className="user-input">
            <input
              id="input-field"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Type your answer here"
              value={userInput}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              maxLength="15"
              autoFocus
              autoComplete="off"
              spellCheck="false"
              onKeyUp={handleKeyUp}
              ref={inputElement}
            />
            {/* <button onClick={checkAnswer}>Check Answer</button> */}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="Bottom-Content">
          <Keyboard onKeyboardButtonPressed={handleInputUpdateFromKeyboard} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TheBigScreen;
```

And this is the code I have for the Timer component...

```
const Timer = ({ startingTime = 60, onTimerEnd }) => {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(startingTime);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimerEnd(); // Call the function when timer reaches zero
    } else {
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        setTimeLeft((prevTime) => (prevTime > 0 ? prevTime - 1 : 0));
      }, 1000);

      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, [timeLeft, onTimerEnd]);

  const radius = 40; // Radius of the circle
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
  const dashOffset =
    circumference - (circumference / startingTime) * (startingTime - timeLeft);

  return (
    <div className="timer-container">
      <svg className="timer-svg" width="120" height="120">
        <circle className="timer-circle" cx="60" cy="60" r={radius} />
        <text
          x="50%"
          y="50%"
          textAnchor="middle"
          dominantBaseline="middle"
          dy="0.25rem" // Adjust to centre the text in the centre of the circle.
          className="timer-text"
        >
          {timeLeft}
        </text>
        <circle
          className="timer-path"
          cx="60"
          cy="60"
          r={radius}
          style={{
            strokeDasharray: circumference,
            strokeDashoffset: dashOffset,
          }}
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

Thank you for looking at this and any help you can give me. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `Timer` component re-renders and the `useEffect()`s dependencies have changed, React will first run the cleanup function that you're returning from within the `useEffect()` and then it'll run the setup function.

In your case, your dependencies are  `timeLeft` and `onTimerEnd`. The `timeLeft` dependency only changes when you update your state, so that's ok, but the `onTimerEnd` function on the other hand changes every time the parent `TheBigScreen` is re-rendered (which happens when you update your state when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>).  That's because each time your parent component rerenders, all the top-level code in your `TheBigScreen` component executes again, making you recreate a new function object. Since the parent rerenders, this causes the child `Timer` component to rerender, and since you're passing a new function object as the `onTimerEnd` prop, `useEffect` sees this as a change in the dependency array, and so, it will run that cleanup function that will clear the current timer.

Instead, you should make your `onTimerEnd` function stable across renders so that you get the same function object back for each rerender, which you can do with `useCallback()`:

```
const onTimerEnd = useCallback(() => { 
  console.log("Timer has ended.");
}, []);
```

This works since your `onTimerEnd` doesn't have any dependencies on the external state, so we can pass an empty dependency array.

---

But things get a little more complicated if your `onTimerEnd` function needs to see [reactive values](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#specifying-reactive-dependencies) such as state (eg: your `correctAnswers` or `incorrectAnswers` state). In this case, you would need to provide those reactive state values as dependencies to the `useCallback()` function, but that now means you'll be creating a new function object again when those values change, causing a similar issue to what you have now. One option to get around that is to use the [`useInterval()`](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) custom hook for your interval. This way the interval doesn't get cleared and the interval callback will have access to the latest state values. Alternatively, there's an experimental hook, currently called [`useEffectEvent()`](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-effect-event) (currently available under `experimental_useEffectEvent`), that would allow you to declare `onTimerEnd` as an effect-event and avoid needing to pass it as a dependency to your timer's `useEffect()` while also allowing it to "see" the latest reactive values. That would subsequentially stop the cleanup function from running and pausing your timer. That hook is currently experimental so its behavior may change. You could also currently write your own rough shim:

```js
// Rough example of how `useEffectEvent` could be implemented.
// Taken from: https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#internal-implementation
function useEffectEvent(handler) {
  const handlerRef = useRef(null);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    handlerRef.current = handler;
  });
  return useCallback((...args) => {
    const fn = handlerRef.current;
    return fn(...args);
  }, []);
}
```

Note that this doesn't represent how the `useEffectEvent()` hook will behave, but it aims to mimic the behavior where the callback is stable across rerenders (thus no need to provide it as a dependency), but is also able to see the latest state/reactive values in the code that's it's been declared in:

```js
const onTimerEnd = useEffectEvent(() => {
  // can now access up to date state values such as `correctAnswers`
  console.log("Timer has ended.");
});
```

Which then allows you to remove the `onTimerEnd` dependency, preventing the cleanup function from clearing your timer:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (timeLeft === 0) {
    onTimerEnd(); // Call the function when timer reaches zero
  } else {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft((prevTime) => (prevTime > 0 ? prevTime - 1 : 0));
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, [timeLeft /*, onTimerEnd <-- doesn't need to be a dependency anymore */]);
```