# Stale state inside an event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-state-management

I have a JS library (Cytoscape) inside my React component. The library need to be handled events with set event handler functions (on diagram/ component initilazation).

The problem is that inside these events the state is stale - it only gets the first state because of the closure.

```
 const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState()
 const handleMouseOverNode = (e) => {
    // this only gets the initial value but doesn't update when state changes
    console.log (otherState)
 }
 useEffect(() => {
        cyRef.current.on('mouseover', 'node', handleMouseOverNode);
    }
    return () => {
        cyRef.current.removeListener('mouseover');
    };
 }, [cyRef.current]);
```

How do I get the real (non stale) state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experimental [`useEffectEvent`](https://react.dev/reference/react/experimental_useEffectEvent) would solve this problem eventually. You can currently use it, but it's not stable, and might break in the future (see [Declaring an Effect Event](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-effect-event)):

```
import { experimental_useEffectEvent as useEffectEvent } from 'react';

const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState()

// wrap with useEffectEvent
const handleMouseOverNode = useEffectEvent((e) => {
  console.log(otherState)
})

useEffect(() => {
  cyRef.current.on('mouseover', 'node', handleMouseOverNode);

  return () => {
    cyRef.current.removeListener('mouseover');
  };
}, [cyRef.current]); // no need to add handleMouseOverNode as a dep
```

Currently the clunky solution is to use another ref to hold the updated value:

```
const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState()

const otherStateRef = useRef(otherState) // create a ref

// always update the ref with current value
useEffect(() => {
  otherStateRef.current = otherState
})

useEffect(() => {
  const handleMouseOverNode = (e) => {
    console.log(otherStateRef.current) // get the value from the ref
  }
  
  cyRef.current.on('mouseover', 'node', handleMouseOverNode);

  return () => {
    cyRef.current.removeListener('mouseover');
  };
}, [cyRef.current]);
```

Comment: I Used the ` useRef(otherState)` solution. That is the best in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your effect has a dependency on the `handleMouseOverNode` as it uses that function within it, so you should provide `handleMouseOverNode` as a dependency in the dependency array:

```js
const [otherState, setOtherState] = useState()
const handleMouseOverNode = (e) => {
  // should now be the latest state value
  console.log (otherState);
}
useEffect(() => {
  cyRef.current.on('mouseover', 'node', handleMouseOverNode);

  return () => {
    cyRef.current.removeListener('mouseover');
  };
}, [cyRef.current, handleMouseOverNode]);
```

With this approach, your `useEffect` will recreate the event listener on every rerender, giving it access to call the newest `handleMouseOverNode` function that has access to the latest state. I suggest that you optimize this though, as a new function reference will be created on every rerender with the above approach. Instead, you can memoize the callback function so that it's only recreated (and thus your even listeners are only re-added) when your function state changes by using [`useCallback()`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback):

```js
const handleMouseOverNode = useCallback((e) => {
  // this only gets the initial value but doesn't update when state changes
  console.log (otherState)
}, [otherState]);
```

And then pass `handleMouseOverNode` as a dependency to the `useEffect()` as done above.

Comment: Thank you. But what if I don't want that useEffect to run on every state change? Any other alternative?

Comment: @ChenPeleg Use an effect event as Ori Drori suggests, I have an example on a temporary/custom hook you can use if you want to use that instead of the experimental hook [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78010667/5648954)